# Is there a meaning of stripes on RS485, Phone and Ethernet cable?

Tags: cables

I recently bought some RS485 cable, it had two pairs, both had stripes. One was mostly blue with a white stripe and the other was white with a blue stripe.

[image]

I'm mostly used to ethernet with a pair consisting of completely solid and white with a stripe.

Large phone cables have solid with white stripes, and solid.

So is there a meaning to any of these? Is the striping set by manufacturers or have any meaning beyond indicating a pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User @Justme was correct about it being a twisted pair but the stripped line indicates positive and solid colored line indicates negative.

So for an example, let's say you have two twisted pairs: One for RX and TX. Much like RJ45, etc., RS485 will also have RX and TX signals.

[image]
Picture can be found [here](https://pinouts.ru/NetworkCables/ethernet_10_100_1000_pinout.shtml)... Not my picture.
The positive and negative wires are for differential signaling.

You can find more details on that with [this Network Engineering StackExchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57752/what-do-the-positive-and-negative-transmit-and-receive-pins-mean-on-ethern) answer (What do the positive and negative (+/-) transmit and receive pins mean on Ethernet cables?).

Comment: Just note that RS-485 has no *standardized* wiring convention.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [Wikipedia article on TIA/EIA-568](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568).

Comment: @CalebReister Thank you for the additional reading material. However, the link to my picture already provides this information.

Answer (score -2):

It is just to show which wires are twisted as a pair, no electrical meaning.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, and you provide no sources, although it is true that RS-485 does not specify a connector or pinout.

Comment: @CalebReister This answer indicates no sign of plagiarism since there doesn't appear to contain any fundamental theory. Had the answer contain something like, "This is a twisted pair that reduces the amount of electrical noise in the wire blah blah blah. These statistical numbers indicate blah blah blah...", without citing anything, then it would be plagerism. Also, **this is indeed answer even though it is short.** It answers the question, does it not? You also need to do some research on what RS485 is. RS485 is not a connector, it's a standard. You're thinking of DB9 and DB25.

Comment: It is important to be able to identify which conductor is which in a twisted pair cable. -1 for saying that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Of course it is important to determine which conductor is which in a pair. Correct me if I am wrong, but the question was about stripes - it really does not matter if it is stripey blue and stripey white or solid blue and solid white, stripyness does not have an electrical meaning, beyond indicating the pair. In a cable with huge amount of pairs, the stripes may have other colors than white, to separate a blue pair with white stripe from say blue pair with yellow stripe, or whatever the coding happens to be.

Comment: I think the ambiguity of saying "has no electrical meaning" is probably the reason Dwayne downvoted. You're right about wire convention, though.

Comment: @Justme: if you edit your question to remove any ambiguity, I will happily remove my down-vote.  But the stripe is important and there **IS** an electrical meaning!

Comment: @DwayneReid it wasn't my question. In the original question, the asker said he usually sees pairs that contain a solid color wire twisted with striped color/white wire commonly seen in CAT cabling, and this time encountered a pair that had no solid color wire but both wires were striped with color/white, and asked if there is any meaning for the stripes, beyond indicating a pair. I don't think there is any other meaning. So what ambiguity specifically would you like me to resolve about the stripes? They are just color codes to distinguish pairs and wires within a pair, no other meaning, right?

Comment: @Justme: What the original poster described is common with both Telco cable as well as Data (Ethernet) cable.  There are also cable manufacturers who use coloured dots rather than stripes.  The conductor that is mostly one colour can be considered to be that colour.  So a pair that has a mostly blue conductor with white stripe paired with a mostly white conductor that has a blue stripe is ONE pair.  Think of it this way: you have a 100 pair telco cable in your hands.  The pairs are starting to separate.  Because each pair has both colours, you can keep the pairs identified .   To be continued

Comment: The cable that KingDukem described is perfectly suited for low pair counts - there is no chance of ambiguity.  But go more than 5 pairs and you can get into trouble really fast.  The problem that I have with your answer is that you say that there is NO electrical meaning to the colour pairs.  I strongly disagree.  I've spent thousands or tens of thousands of hours working with Telco cable and rely on the pair colours both for pair identification (which is pair 1 vs which is pair 25) as well as phase / polarity.  The colours are incredibly important.